# Playing pokemon go on rpi 4

Tags: pi-4, android, games

I looked around on the internet but all I found were rpi pokemon detectors. I tried using LineageOS ([following this tutorial](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-android-lineageos/)), but it said device not supported, probably because of the root required to get Gapps.

So is there any way to play Pokemon GO on the rpi 4 (8gb)?

Comment: `it said device not supported` ... what is `it` in that statement? .... what is your actual question? ... what is preventing you from playing? ... why are you not asking about that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are able to connect a GPS to the Pi (and configure it properly), you could install Android to it and maaaaybe run Pokemon Go (if you do please write a tutorial about it).
There is also ways to fake GPS locations, as seen here: https://nickfogle.com/breaking-pokemon-go-with-a-raspberry-pi/

Answer (score -2):

Well, I don't know for sure, but I assume, with the correct sensors, a constant, mobile internet connection, and an Android OS, the raspberry pi 4 should be able to run it.

Comment: We look for reliable answers here, not mere assumptions.  Can you please provide something to back this up?